# Does fmt.Print() write to stdout in GoLang?

Tags: go

I may be overthinking this too much, but in GoLang, does `fmt.Print()` write to stdout or do I have to use `os.Stdout.Write`?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Print):

> Print formats using the default formats for its operands and writes to standard output.

So yep, it writes to stdout.

Comment: If it's helpful to anyone else, I had to use `fmt.Println()`. I didn't see any output with `fmt.Print()`

Answer (score 17):

Yes, it does. [From the source code](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/go1.4.1/src/fmt/print.go#L228-L233):

```
// Print formats using the default formats for its operands and writes to standard output.
// Spaces are added between operands when neither is a string.
// It returns the number of bytes written and any write error encountered.
func Print(a ...interface{}) (n int, err error) {
    return Fprint(os.Stdout, a...)
}
```

`os.Stdout` indeed represents the standard output stream.

Answer (score 4):

From the [Print documentation](http://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Print): *Print formats using the default formats for its operands and writes to standard output.*

Comment: There is must be a bug in documentation or code. Now docs says it standard output, but test  prog outputs to stderr. My go version is 1.11.5. More fresh versions seems to fmt.Print to stdout